# VBA to copy value and loop for each row

Tags: vba, macros

I have range of columns with mostly blank cells. I am trying to copy if any of those cells contain a text. For this I have written the following code which works fine for the first row. How to repeat this for each row until the last used row?

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Sheet1.Range("BI2:CZ2")
        For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
        Sheet1.Range("AH2").Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner for editing this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did everything right - only one nuance is missing: after writing to the target cell, you need to move this cell to the right or down. This can be done, for example, like this:

```
Sub copyNonEmptyCells()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, targetCel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Sheet1.Range("BI2:CZ2")
    Set targetCel = Sheet1.Range("AH2")
    For Each cel In SrchRng.Cells
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            targetCel.Value = cel.Value
            Set targetCel = targetCel.Offset(0, 1) ' or (1,0)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

In case you want to concatenate all non-empty values of each row in the range into one cell, as you indicated in your comment, the macro code becomes not much more complicated:

```
Sub joinNonEmptyCells()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, targetCel As Range, oSingleRow As Range
    Set SrchRng = Sheet1.Range("BI2:CZ100")
    Set targetCel = Sheet1.Range("AH2")
    targetCel.Value = ""
    For Each oSingleRow In SrchRng.Rows
        For Each cel In oSingleRow.Cells
            If cel.Value <> "" Then
                targetCel.Value = targetCel.Value & " " & cel.Value
            End If
        Next cel
        targetCel.Value = Trim(targetCel.Text)
        Set targetCel = targetCel.Offset(1, 0)
        targetCel.Value = ""
    Next oSingleRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. I made one change in your response declaring range BI2:CZ2 to BI2:CZ100 and it worked. But if I get two cells with text in the same row, how to handle this part?

Comment: @Rax How would you like to handle such a situation? In your original question and code sample, there was no hint of any special behavior of the algorithm in this case.

Comment: I would like to copy both texts in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It first finds the last row on the sheet. Then, loop through the rows (from row 2 to the last) and set the values if found, in AH.

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
'Get the last row
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow 'Loop the rows
        Set SrchRng = Sheet1.Range("BI" & x & ":CZ" & x)
        For Each cel In SrchRng 'Loop through each row
            If cel.Value <> "" Then
                Sheet1.Range("AH" & x).Value = cel.Value
            End If
        Next cel

    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But if my source and target sheets are different where source begin from row 3 while target begins from row 2, how to handle this situation. Response appreciated.

Comment: @Rax In that case, set x = 3 for the first loop. Then add a new variable, let say `y` before the first loop, set it to 2. And modified `Sheet1.Range("AH" & x).Value = cel.Value` to `Sheet1.Range("AH" & y).Value = cel.Value`.  Add `y = y + 1` before `Next cel`.

Comment: You're awsome. Thanks a lot !!!